# Not sure how to proceed with Caesar's algorithm, cannot print out the deciphered text

Tags: c, cs50

I'm currently trying to convert a plaintext to a ciphertext with a key.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int atoi(string argv);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int k = 0;
    string key = argv[1];
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < strlen(key); k++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(key[k]))
            {
                printf("\nUsage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nSucces!");
            }
            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nUsage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
 
string plaintext = get_string("\nplaintext: ");  

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
{   
    char c = plaintext[i];
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        printf("%c", (c + key) % 26);
    }
}
    
    
}
```

If the character in the string of plaintext is a letter from the alphabet, I want it to move key positions.

I need to apply the following formula: ci = (pi + k) % 26, but it doesn't work out for me. Can someone hint me what I'm doing wrong?

I get the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('string' (aka 'char *') and 'int')
```

Comment: Apart from trying to apply arithmetic to the strings (instead of their indexed elements) you'll need to prevent the key string indexing overflowing too. It should wrap. Also any value `% 26` will be in the range 0..25 which is not a printable character.

Comment: Do *not* print a usage statement in lieu of an error message.  As a user, I would call `./a.out k` and see your usage statement and think "I gave a key.  It is 'k'".  If the problem is that the key needs to be an integer, then say that in the error message.  Print the error message to stderr, and terminate non-zero.  Whenever you print a usage statement (eg, you might consider calling the program with no argument a valid request for a usage statement), print it to stdout and exit (0).  Never exit non-zero without printing an error message, and never write a usage statement to stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `(c + key)` is the binary expression that provokes the error. `c` is a char (which is technically an `int`). `key` is a string, as declared and initialized here `string key = argv[1];`. There is a function in `stdlib.c` library called `atoi`, so it is a questionable decision to declare your own. That library needs to be `include`'d to use the atoi function. That is the function that can be used to convert `key` to an integer.

Comment: Thank you! This helped incredibly.